# rsync link_stat No such file or directory when using wildcard

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to copy all XML files whose name start with foo

```
rsync /source/dir/foo*.xml /dest/dir
```

If there aren't any files matching this pattern rsync throws error:

```
rsync: link_stat "/source/dir/foo*.xml" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Should I care about this error? Is there a way to suppress it? If there's at least one file matching the pattern then the command runs without errors.

Comment: rsync --ignore-errors ... ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a **bash** setting to avoid this:

```
shopt -s failglob
```

From the man page:

> **failglob**
>    If set, patterns which fail to match filenames during pathname expansion result in an expansion error.

Otherwise, you can use an `if` to just not run the rsync when there's nothing to do.

---

If you really do want to sync nothing, so that it deletes files that don't exist, then the command might be like this:

```
rsync --include 'foo*.xml' \
      --exclude '**' \
      --delete \
      /source/dir/ /dest/dir
```

The trailing slash is significant.